# In a cell, how do I position and size a view created from a nib with Auto Layout?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uiview, autolayout

I have a `UITableViewCell` subclass that I'm electing to set all positioning up in its `layoutSubviews` method. I have a special view I've created (essentially a view with a `UILabel` in it) as a subview of this cell, and I want to position it correctly in `layoutSubviews`, but I cannot figure out how.

Every other view I calculate what its position should be manually, and then call setFrame. This seems weird with this special view I've created as it's created from a nib and laid out using Auto Layout. But the cell itself doesn't use Auto Layout so I'm unsure what to do.

Constraint-wise the special view with the label in it just has the label positioned 15pt in from each size of the view it's contained in.

In `layoutSubviews` I want to essentially keep this logic that insets it intact, but make sure in terms of the cell that it's positioned and sized properly within the cell. So essentially I want to keep the Auto Layout logic that keeps the label within the special view positioned intact, but allow me to position and size *the whole view itself* within the cell using `setFrame`. Basically a view created from a nib with Auto Layout used inside a cell that elects not to use Auto Layout.

I tried basically calling `sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero` to deduce what size it should be with Auto Layout, then position it, but it returns an absurdly large size that doesn't make sense. Even if I return a manually size, I get "constraint conflict" warnings in the console that one or more of my Auto Layout constraints for setting up the label within the cell will be ignored.

How should I be doing this? How should I make the view's subviews respect its Auto Layout system, but allow me to position the cohesive view itself however I please?

Answer (score 2):

Your special view  has all valid constraints. It can determine its width and height from its auto laid subviews.

Instead of using, `sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero` use `- (CGSize)systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:(CGSize)targetSize` with target size `UILayoutFittingCompressedSize` or `UILayoutFittingExpandedSize`.

And then set your frame with width and height from this returned size, and origin.x/.y as per your like.

In case you label is multiline do set its `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` before getting fitting size.

Edit : tested and worked!